# Selecting rows where there is repetition in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table like below:

```
Name   Score
-----  ----- 
Don    3
Don    4
Don    0
Pat    3
Cat    5
```

How to write a query that will filter out Name where the score is 0? I.e.: In the above table, the query must not return the Name "Don" since one of the rows for Don contains 0. (I'm using Oracle db BTW.)

Comment: Removed the `plsql` tag (and replaced it with `oracle`) as there is no indication that PL/SQL is actually needed for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name
from your_table
group by name
having sum(case when score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is there any other way to do this? I'm using this solution as a sub-logic in my query and having some difficulty. In my project there is a similar table with year column. I'm trying to get the rows where a person has some score in a particular year but has never had a 0. So I was wondering how to include this in my where condition.

Comment: If this query does not work for you then should ask a new question with the exact requirements. Alone from your comment I can't tell  what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that usually jumps to ones mind is something with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM players p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM players p2
    WHERE p1.Name = p2.Name
    AND p2.Score = 0
)
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle showing it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/228c2/1), returning

```
| NAME | SCORE |
|------|-------|
|  Cat |     5 |
|  Pat |     3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar, but if you want other ways:

```
select Name
from   T1
group by Name
having Min( Score ) > 0;
```

This assumes that `Score` cannot be negative which, from context, looks like a pretty safe assumption. It would still work if you wanted to omit anyone with a score of zero or less. If you wanted to omit only zero but still pass negative values, then change the test to `having Min( Abs( Score )) > 0`.